# How long is a typical play session of Artemis: Spaceship Bridge Simulator?

Tags: artemis-spaceship-bridge-simulator

I'm looking to set up and play Artemis during a gaming event and would like to know what a typical play time is like.

People will be coming and going during the event, and it would be nice to let people know when they can get in on the action.

I've not played the game at all and have no idea if its mission based, and each mission has its own specific amount of time required to complete, or if its just open ended and you slowly make your way through a story.

Any info about how the amount of time it takes to play from people that have played it before would be wonderful.

Game Website: http://www.artemis.eochu.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not played all missions or variants of the game, but from my experience, the games go fairly quickly. I would estimate them somewhere between 5-30 minutes depending on game mode, number of player ships, player performance, and the difficulty setting.

The game is mission/simulation based and the enemies are constantly advancing to achieve their objectives, so there are no hard time limits or open ended gameplay.

I would definitely recommend playing some before trying to play the game at an event as each station has its own controls and game interface (some of which are very confusing initially).

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Also note that players can leave/join/shuffle mid-mission, so it's not that big of a deal

Comment: Don't forget that the simulations can be preprogrammed with a mission timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer 30 minutes to two hours for real games.

Theoretically if everyone knows how to play you can have as short as a 15 minute game, but there's little challenge to it.  30 minutes is more satisfying.  If you're teaching people plan on an hour, unless you've got six teachers.

You can just give them a baptism in fire.  The latter gets them playing instantly, but tends to unleash the naggy captain aspect of the game where the captain starts correcting everything done wrong which quickly makes the game unfun.

A real game, with the difficulty cranked can easily run an hour and a half to two hours, especially if you're not cruising around in a Juggernaut.